# ASP.NET Brackets In Url stopping forms authentication / cookies working

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a ASP.NET website deployed under IIS uisng virtual directories. I'm using forms authentication.

For some reason my client has deployed it under a strange virtual directory name which has lots of brackets

`http://localhost/(DirectoryName(1))/`

This seems to stop forms authentication working. Does anyone know why?

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ObscureBugASPNETDoesntHandleCookiesWithNonstandardServerNames.aspx

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q312461

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I had set up a host name of

> `http://local_test`

and this also stopped forms authentication from working.  Eventually I tracked it down to the underscore "_" in a domain name not allowing cookies to be set and therefore forms authentication not working.  My guess is this is something related.  The "(" and ")" are preventing the forms authentication cookie from getting set.

Comment: From your comments, it looks like you found the problem.  Cool!

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that if you use cookie-less sessions, the session ID is bundled up in parentheses - so causing confusion, as the system will expect the bit in parentheses to be a session ID. See [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx). A screenshot from it:

[alt text http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Aa479314.cookieless01(en-us,MSDN.10).gif](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Aa479314.cookieless01(en-us,MSDN.10).gif)